# Scroll view when keyboard appears for UITextView, but not for the UITextField that's on the same view

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield, uitextview

I am using this code to scroll the view up when I start editing a `UITextView`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Login.keyboardWillShow), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(Login.keyboardWillHide), name: NSNotification.Name.UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)

}

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {

    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
        }
    }

}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let keyboardSize = (notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y != 0{
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
        }
    }
}
```

However, I also have a `UITextField` at the top of this view, and the view also scrolls when I begin editing it. I do not want this to happen. How can I change my code to only scroll when the `UITextView` keyboard is active and not when the `UITextField` keyboard is activated?

Comment: Don't blindly scroll by changing the origin by the height of the keyboard. Calculate if and by how much you need to scroll to make the new first responder visible.

Answer (score 1):

Try this piece of code, user textview delgate

// scrollBy - pass the height you want your scrollview to be scrolled when keyboard appears

```
 func textViewDidBeginEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
    {
         scrView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: scrollBy), animated: true)

     }

    func textViewDidEndEditing(_ textView: UITextView)
    {
        scrView.setContentOffset(CGPoint.init(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)

        self.view.endEditing(true);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that.

Answer (score -3):

Instead of Coding i would Suggest you should add TPkeyboard File in your project this would toggle the keyboard whenever required